# How do I resolve these ESP-TLS connection errors?

Tags: http, twilio, httpclient, esp32, esp-idf

This program is running on an ESP32 and sending SMS alerts using the Twilio API. The board connects to WiFi fine but is giving the following errors in the monitor and ultimately failing to send any messages:

```
␛[0;31mE (30400) esp-tls-mbedtls: No server verification option set in esp_tls_cfg_t structure. Check esp_tls API reference␛[0m
␛[0;31mE (30400) esp-tls-mbedtls: Failed to set client configurations, returned [0x8017] (ESP_ERR_MBEDTLS_SSL_SETUP_FAILED)␛[0m
␛[0;31mE (30400) esp-tls-mbedtls: No server verification option set in esp_tls_cfg_t structure. Check esp_tls API reference␛[0m
␛[0;31mE (30420) esp-tls: create_ssl_handle failed␛[0m
␛[0;31mE (30430) esp-tls: Failed to open new connection␛[0m

␛[0;31mE (30480) HTTP_CLIENT: Connection failed, sock < 0␛[0m
```

I have already changed the sdkconfig settings to "Allow potentially insecure options" and to "Skip server certificate verification by default" (both in the sdkconfig file and in the SDK Configuration Editor menu on VSCode.

The following is the code for my client config:

```
    esp_http_client_config_t config = {
        .url = twilio_url,
        .method = HTTP_METHOD_POST,
        .auth_type = HTTP_AUTH_TYPE_BASIC,
    };

    esp_http_client_handle_t client = esp_http_client_init(&config);
    esp_http_client_set_header(client, "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    esp_http_client_set_username(client, account_sid);
    esp_http_client_set_password(client, auth_token);
```

Answer (score 0):

Ended up adding the following:

```
#include "esp_crt_bundle.h"

esp_http_client_config_t config = {
    .url = twilio_url,
    .method = HTTP_METHOD_POST,
    .auth_type = HTTP_AUTH_TYPE_BASIC,
    .transport_type = HTTP_TRANSPORT_OVER_SSL,
    .crt_bundle_attach = esp_crt_bundle_attach,
};
```

And it's now working great!